# Outbound Messaging Error -The domain name wasn't in the supported set of domain names

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage, ssl

We're using Workflow Rules with Outbound Messages and Salesforce seems to have a problem with our SSL certificate.

The Outbound Messaging Delivery Status page show a message with a Delivery Failure Reason of "**javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: The domain name api.example.com wasn't in the supported set of domain names in...**". Unfortunately SFDC truncates the end of the error. Switching to HTTP works as expected.

Comment: It might be best to raise this as a support case. They say they support it, but it appears that they don't. The Root GoDaddy SHA 1 thumbprint reported in chrome appears to match that listed by Salesforce (assuming they aren't case sensitive).

Comment: SFDC won't handle this as a support case unless we have a paid support plan as they consider it a developer issue, they told us to just post on the forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We finally found the problem!

**Salesforce.com does not support [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). You must use IP-based SSL.**

If you're trying to make an outbound HTTPS request from SFDC to your server which is hosted in some cloud platform (Windows Azure in our case) then chances are you are using SNI for SSL.

SNI allows multiple SSL certificates to be assigned to the same IP address. Modern browsers support it which is why the certificate seems to be installed correctly. Unfortunately, Apex & Outbound Messages do not support it. You must switch your server to use the traditional, more widely supported, and sometimes more expensive IP-based configuration.

We discovered the problem after using OpenSSL to make a request to our site and noticed that our certificate was not being returned. Instead, a certificate for Windows Azure was being returned. This was confusing because other tools and sites such as https://www.digicert.com/help all indicated that our correct certificate was being returned. This is probably because those tools support SNI. Anything that does not support SNI will retrieve an incorrect certificate for the request which is what was causing our Outbound Message to fail.